# Error installing Gdata module

Tags: python, gdata, failed-installation

I'm trying to install the Gdata module on my system. I'm using Python 2.7.1 on Windows 7. I should admit, I'm not very experienced installing modules without resorting to binaries before, so any advice would be appreciated.

I downloaded the Gdata module and extracted its contents to C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages. I then tried going to the Windows command prompt, and typed C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\gdata-2.0.17\setup.py install. While that seemed initially successful, it ran into an error, namely "package directory 'src\atom' does not exist". Now, I checked, and there is a folder named src and another folder in it named atom, so I'm not sure what's happening here.

I tried running the setup.py file directly (which I've discovered doesn't generally work, but thought it was worth a shot anyway), but all I got was an error: "no commands supplied".

What do I do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, install [easy_install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#windows) (you can also use 'pip').

Open a console, go to C:\Python27\Scripts\ and run the command:

`easy_install gdata`

Altering the '\site-packages' content is not the best idea, because you should consider it a Python internal directory, not a user-editable directory. Just use your favourite packaging tool to download/install all the packages you need.